# unable to count past the first arrays values when trying to count multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, counting

The following takes place in WordPress..

```
// get the current page author

$curauth    = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', 
$author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));

// get the current page authors id (in this case its 2)

$author_id  = $curauth->ID;

// set the $args to get the value of the users meta_key named 'followers'

$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'followers',
);

// setup the get_users() query to use the $args

$users  = get_users($args);

// setup a foreach loop to loop through all the users we just queried getting the value of each users 'followers' field

foreach ($users as $user) {

// $user->folllowers returns:
// 2
// 1,3,5
// 3,4,5
// 3,5,1,4
// 3,4,5,1
// 1,2
// which is a series of comma separated strings.
// so then i turn each string into an array:

    $array = array($user->followers);

    // go through each array and count the items that contain the authors id

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $counts = array_count_values($array);
        echo $counts[$author_id];
    }

}
```

the result is that i get a value of "1" but it should be "2" since the author_id in this example is 2 and there are 2 strings that contain 2 in them.

i feel like its only checking for the author_id in the first array in the series of arrays.

can you help me figure out what im doing wrong?

Comment: You need to actually split the string. Try $array = explode(",", $user->followers);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
 $array = array($user->followers);
```

to

```
 $array = explode(",", $user->followers);
```

Because say you have `$followers ="3,4,5,1";` Then:

```
$array = array($followers); 
print_r($array);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 3,4,5,1
)


$array = explode(",", $followers);  
print_r($array);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 1
)
```

Comment: ok cool thanks that looks like it works. now i get a results of '11' which i guess is that it found 1 result in 1 array and a second 1 result in a second array, which i guess is correct. so now how do i add the two 1's together to get 2?

Comment: Thats easy. Do this: `$counts= array_count_values ($array );` Then $count will have an array with the values as index and its count as values. Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php